# asp.net multiple urls pointing to same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, social-networking

I am working on a social networking site where we are implementing profiles, pages, groups etc. At this stage, we are working with profiles and pages. They both have wall where user can put some status, pics etc, more like facebook wall.

Now a controller WallController can be accessed by two different urls.

```
www.mysite.com/profile/121/some-user/wall
and
www.mysite.com/page/222/some-page/wall
```

On the left hand side of the page, I load some basic information (name etc) and a menu.
saying

```
www.mysite.com/profile/121/some-user/photos
www.mysite.com/profile/121/some-user/videos
www.mysite.com/profile/121/some-user/songs
```

This applies to both (page and profile).

here is my route for page

```
   routes.MapRoute(
           "Page-wall", // Route name
           "page/{id}/{name}/wall", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "wall", action = "details", id = "", name = "" },
           new { id = @"\d+" },
           new string[] { "PagesNameSpace.Controllers" } // Parameter defaults
           );
```

and for profile

```
      routes.MapRoute(
           "profile-wall", // Route name
           "profile/{id}/{name}/wall", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "wall", action = "details", id = "", name = "" },
           new { id = @"\d+" },
           new string[] { "ProfileNameSpace.Controllers" } // Parameter defaults
           );
```

Now, the problem is, I have to identify what object is accessing the url. here is my WallController

```
public class WallController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Details(long id, string name)
     {

        return View(LoadWallData(id));
     }

}
```

I see a route value dictionary as a solution, but would like to see, what is the best solution for this kind for situations.

help will be appreciated.

Regards
Parminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do the following, you just add the values into your routes:

Change your controller:

```
public class WallController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Details(long id, string name, string obj)//added param
     {

        return View(LoadWallData(id));
     }
}
```

And then your routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "Page-wall", // Route name
           "page/{id}/{name}/wall", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "wall", action = "details", id = "", name = "",
                                                   /*See this>>>> */ obj="page"},
           new { id = @"\d+" },
           new string[] { "PagesNameSpace.Controllers" } // Parameter defaults
           );

routes.MapRoute(
           "profile-wall", // Route name
           "profile/{id}/{name}/wall", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "wall", action = "details", id = "", name = "",
                                             /*See this>>>> */ obj="profile" },
           new { id = @"\d+" },
           new string[] { "ProfileNameSpace.Controllers" }
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

using `((System.Web.Routing.Route)(Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Route)).Url` you can get the URL with parameter values from  MapRoute.

Answer (score 0):

I feel, I would go with this approach.

```
public class WallController : Controller
{
 public ActionResult Details(string type ,long id, string name)//added param
 {

    return View(LoadWallData(id));
 }
 }
```

and my routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "wall-default", // Route name
       "{type}/{id}/{name}/wall", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "wall", action = "details", id = "", name = "",
                                                               type="profile"},
       new { id = @"\d+" },
       new string[] { "PagesNameSpace.Controllers" } // Parameter defaults
       );
```

Now just by passing the type parameter, I can get action link for page and profile.

thanks a lot to everyone.

Regards